# how to show value from hidden box when button onclick in php loop

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

i trying to build shop simple site for learning but i got stuck when i click button. when i click it nothing happen. it should showing text from value on hidden button when i click button.

below is my php code

```
$i=1;
                         while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($varresultP)){
                           echo "<button type='button' class='btn btn-outline-primary' onclick='myFunction()' >".$rows['var_name']."</button>";
                           echo "<input type='hidden'  name='price' value=".$rows['price']." id='price{$i}'>";
                           echo "<input type='hidden' value=".$rows['id']." id='id{$i}'>";
                           echo "<input type='hidden' value=".$rows['quantity']." id='quantity{$i}'>";
                            
                            $i++;
                         }
```

the result is multiple button appear but nothing happen when i click button. total button is based from database how many data have.

below is my jsquery

```
function myFunction() {
  for(var i=1; i<5; i++){
  var x = document.getElementById("price"+i).value;
  document.getElementById("sendPrice").innerHTML = x;

  var x = document.getElementById("id"+i).value;
  document.getElementById("idDiv").innerHTML = x;

  var x = document.getElementById("quantity"+i).value;
  document.getElementById("showQuantity").innerHTML = x;
  }
}
```

value from `id(price)` that i want show on div `id(sendPrice)`, value from `id(id)` that i need to show in href button, value from `id(quantity)` that i need it will appear on div `id(showQuantity)` when button is onclick.

below is html code

```
    <div class ='row' style='padding: 30px; width: 100px;'><p>USD: <label class='p2--semi-bold c-red' id='sendPrice'></p></label></div>
<div class ='row' style='padding: 30px; width: 100px;'><p>Productid: <label id='idDiv'></p></label></div>
<div class ='row' style='padding: 30px; width: 100px;'><p>Quantity: <label id='showQuantity'></p></label></div>
```

Comment: If this is a pure JS problem, please show the **generated** markup. Also, what have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: its already solve sir by answer below.  just need to remove for loop in javascript and add `i` in function. also change `id=id` to `id=ids`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add `{$i}` to your `onclick='myFunction()'` like `onclick='myFunction({$i})'`

second in your javascript remove the for loop and add `i` to `function myFunction() {` like `function myFunction(i) {`

**Demo**

```js
function myFunction(i) {
  var x = document.getElementById("price" + i).value;
  document.getElementById("sendPrice").innerHTML = x;

  var x = document.getElementById("id" + i).value;
  document.getElementById("idDiv").innerHTML = x;

  var x = document.getElementById("quantity" + i).value;
  document.getElementById("showQuantity").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<button type='button' class='btn btn-outline-primary' onclick='myFunction(1)'>".$rows['var_name']."</button>
<input type='hidden' name='price' value=".$rows['price']. ROW1" id='price1'>
<input type='hidden' value=".$rows['id']. ROW1" id='id1'>
<input type='hidden' value=".$rows['quantity']. ROW1" id='quantity1'>";

<button type='button' class='btn btn-outline-primary' onclick='myFunction(2)'>".$rows['var_name']."</button>
<input type='hidden' name='price' value=".$rows['price']. ROW2" id='price2'>
<input type='hidden' value=".$rows['id']. ROW2" id='id2'>
<input type='hidden' value=".$rows['quantity']. ROW2" id='quantity2'>";



<div id="sendPrice"></div>
<div id="idDiv"></div>
<div id="showQuantity"></div>
```

Comment: thanks sir. its works for `<div id="sendPrice"></div>` but for `<div id="idDiv"></div>` and `<div id="showQuantity"></div>` nothing happen meaning still not working on that both div.

Comment: without seeing all the relevant html code, then I can't give you a clear answer

Comment: i see it. i have edit that by adding html code.

Comment: thanks . about id(id) i have change to id(ids) and its working. Thanks for your help. its fully working now ;D